# c# how to bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream)

Tags: c#

can somebody tell me why this picture not outpotstream on browser
just i want to write over image with my custom ttf and show it on browser
do not want to save it on server

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string fontName = "sky-bold.ttf";

    PrivateFontCollection pfcoll = new PrivateFontCollection();
    //put a font file under a Fonts directory within your application root
    pfcoll.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~/Fonts/" + fontName));
    FontFamily ff = pfcoll.Families[0];
    string firstText = Label1.Text;


    PointF firstLocation = new PointF(233f, 730f);

    //put an image file under a Images directory within your application root
    string imageFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/HappyEid.jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        using (Font f = new Font(ff, 30, FontStyle.Bold))
        {

            graphics.DrawString(firstText, f, Brushes.SaddleBrown, firstLocation);

        }
    }
    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here?  This looks like webforms.  As such, I don't know how you expect it to handle a random stream of data.  You haven't set any headers to help the browser know what you are even sending.  If you did that properly, it would try to download the file (probably, can't see how this is called right now).  You need to share what you expect to happen, what's happening and enough code to replicate the problem.  Right now, you are missing all of that.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Until you share the things I outlined above, no I can't.

Comment: I have nothing else
I just want to download the image as a maximum of saving it on the server